# Алгоритм генерации SMS-кода

Tags: алгоритм, sms, генераторы

Кто-нибудь знает, какие алгоритмы используются при генерации SMS-кодов для привязки телефонных номеров к аккаунтам? Используется ли при этом номер телефона или просто берётся случайный незанятый на текущий момент код?

Comment: Какой смысл заморачиваться на одноразовый код со временем жизни 5 минут? простой RAND()...

Comment: Не занятый код кстати не нужен, просто случайный. Ведь при привязке обычно кроме кода передают повторно и аккаунт и/или номер телефона

Comment: @Akina не простой RAND() - а криптографически стойкий. Иначе, запросив несколько активаций на известные номера, с малым интервалом времени, можно угадать последовательность, и, соответственно, число отправленное на чужой номер. Лучше всего, аппаратный генератор случайных чисел.

Comment: @Chorkov Да нахрен такие сложности? инициализируем генератор микросекундами таймера - и можешь обугадываться сверху донизу...

Comment: @Akina - нужны-нужны. Стейт обычного rand() - всего 32 бита

Comment: @gbg И что? вот у тебя 32-битное случайное число, которое к тому же нужно угадать с первого раза. И при генерации которого используется в достаточно высокой степени случайный seed (микросекунды из текущего времени). Вот ты правда думаешь, что это реально?